# Viewer responded with a status of 404. No issue with uploading / translating model, but access blocked in viewer api

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am trying to load a new model to Forge Viewer. I am using the react based viewer here:

https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-react-boiler.nodejs

It seems like that I have access to model derivative API, but not the viewer api. I was able to upload and translate the model, but my access was blocked in the viewer api. The console is showing

"The resource failed in :3000/api/forge/user:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found). "

"viewer3D.js?v=6.2:58723 No access token is provided, but authorization requested. This is a problem.
reportError @ viewer3D.js?v=6.2:58723"

I tried the same with an older viewer based on:
https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-javascript-extract.spreadsheet

But everything worked fine, and I was able to view the model after uploading and translation.

Does anyone know what might be wrong?

Comment: Did you follow the [README](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-react-boiler.nodejs/blob/master/README.md)? What resources failed with 404? Can [save your console output](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/#working_with_the_console_history) and share it via https://justpaste.it/ so we can investigate? Alternatively you can try another react sample [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-react-express-headless)

Comment: Hi, thank you so much. I am following the README, I actually been working with forge-react-boiler.nodejs for the last 2-3 month now. I just encountered the problem recently in the last 2 weeks or so when I am trying to upload a new model. I am going to post the console output for the 404 in the original post for clarity.

Comment: Is the node backend up and running? Looking at the errors the frontend was unable to retrieve access token for the viewer or user data through the backend services. Did you make any changes to the code? Can you pull from the upstream to reset any changes and try again?

Comment: The backend is up and running, and the problem has to do with the tokens retrieval. I have made changes to the code, but only modifying and adding to some of the extensions. Can the problem be with my access for the viewer api?